# Errors in debug/AndroidManifest

Tags: xml, debugging, manifest

Getting errors in the debug manifest.  Found a workaround by disabling AAPT2, but I'd rather get to the root of the issue.  In addition to the errors there are various attributes "not allowed here" and "URI not registered"(all only in debug manifest).

debug/AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- suppress ALL -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sam.duluthbikes"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="20"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="25.3.0" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sam.duluthbikes.MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.sam.duluthbikes.MainActivity" />

        <fragment android:name=".AboutFragment" />
        <fragment android:name=".DiscountFragment" />
        <fragment android:name=".EventsFragment" />
        <fragment android:name=".ReportFragment" />
        <fragment android:name=".ToursFragment" />
        <fragment android:name=".RideHistoryFragment" />

        <activity android:name="com.example.sam.duluthbikes.EndRideActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sam.duluthbikes.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

main/AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress ALL -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sam.duluthbikes">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <fragment android:name=".AboutFragment" />
        <fragment android:name=".DiscountFragment" />
        <fragment android:name=".EventsFragment" />
        <fragment android:name=".ReportFragment" />
        <fragment android:name=".ToursFragment" />
        <fragment android:name=".RideHistoryFragment" />
        <activity android:name=".EndRideActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Errors

```xml
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources]
C:\Users\barda\Desktop\College\Fall2017\SoftwareEngineering\GroupBikes\duluthBikes-master\duluthBikes-master\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(72) error: unknown element <fragment> found.
Error:(73) error: unknown element <fragment> found.
Error:(74) error: unknown element <fragment> found.
Error:(75) error: unknown element <fragment> found.
Error:(76) error: unknown element <fragment> found.
Error:(77) error: unknown element <fragment> found.
Error:(72) unknown element <fragment> found.
Error:(73) unknown element <fragment> found.
Error:(74) unknown element <fragment> found.
Error:(75) unknown element <fragment> found.
Error:(76) unknown element <fragment> found.
Error:(77) unknown element <fragment> found.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 1s
Information:16 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Solved by simply removing fragment elements.

Answer (score 1):

You may have an open directory which has a lock on that folder. Thus the IDE cannot delete it during recompilation.

If you check to see if you have that window open - close that folder first, and then run

Build->clean project.

and then

Build->rebuild project it may work for you.

Another thing you can try is to delete the intermediate folders and rebuild them from scratch. In short, the issue is related to the caching of build files.

Answer (score 0):

try: Build->clean project, and build project again